# column-count moves part of div to next column

Tags: css, flexbox, css-grid, masonry, css-multicolumn-layout

I want to build a 2 column masonry grid. I tried using `column-count` but if you look at the last grid item - the text is split to the next column for some reason. And when I tried using flex, the items won't align properly in masonry form.

```css
.workshop {
  width: 100% !important;
  margin: 0 0 1rem 0 !important;
  padding: 0 15px;
  float: right;
}

.workshop-img {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  float: right;
  width: 100%;
}

.workshop-date {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  right: 0;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  background: white;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 20px 0 0 20px;
  color: black;
}

.js-wpv-view-layout {
  column-count: 2;
  -webkit-column-count: 2;
  column-gap: 15px;
  -webkit-column-gap: 15px;
  float: right;
  width: 100%;
  direction: rtl;
}

.workshop-title {
  margin-top: 1rem;
}

.workshop-promo {
  position: relative;
  float: right;
  margin-top: 1rem;
}

.workshop-promo p,
.workshop-promo a {
  color: black;
  text-align: justify;
}
```

```html
<div id="wpv-view-layout-10173" class="js-wpv-view-layout">



  <!-- WPV_Infinite_Scroll -->
  <!-- WPV_Infinite_Scroll_Insert -->
  <div class="workshop">
    <div class="workshop-img">
      <a href="http://outofsite.co.il/liat/workshop/%d7%a1%d7%93%d7%a0%d7%90-%d7%9b%d7%aa%d7%95%d7%9e%d7%94-%d7%a2%d7%9d-%d7%93%d7%9c%d7%99%d7%aa-%d7%a7%d7%a4%d7%9c%d7%9f/"><img width="800" height="798" src="http://outofsite.co.il/liat/wp-content/uploads/2018/12/Dalit-kaplan-1.jpg" class="attachment-full size-full wp-post-image" alt=""></a>
      <div class="workshop-date">
        נובמבר, 2018
      </div>

    </div>
    <div class="workshop-title">
      <h3><a href="http://outofsite.co.il/liat/workshop/%d7%a1%d7%93%d7%a0%d7%90-%d7%9b%d7%aa%d7%95%d7%9e%d7%94-%d7%a2%d7%9d-%d7%93%d7%9c%d7%99%d7%aa-%d7%a7%d7%a4%d7%9c%d7%9f/">סדנא כתומה עם דלית קפלן</a></h3>
      <p>מספר מפגשים: 1
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="workshop-promo">
      <a href="http://outofsite.co.il/liat/workshop/%d7%a1%d7%93%d7%a0%d7%90-%d7%9b%d7%aa%d7%95%d7%9e%d7%94-%d7%a2%d7%9d-%d7%93%d7%9c%d7%99%d7%aa-%d7%a7%d7%a4%d7%9c%d7%9f/">
        <p>תודו שאם לשים משקפיים ורודות אז שיהיו מקרונים. אז דלית ואני רקחנו לכם סדנא כתומה לכבוד טנקסגיבינג, עם פחזניות וסטיקי באנס ומלא הפתעות כתומות אחרות. ורק בשביל הפאן נגיע בפיג'מות, נדליק את האח ואם תהיו ילדים טובים נעשה לכם גם סיידר.&nbsp;אם כבר
          אז כבר.</p>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="workshop">
    <div class="workshop-img">
      <a href="http://outofsite.co.il/liat/workshop/%d7%91%d7%99%d7%a9%d7%95%d7%9c-%d7%a8%d7%95%d7%90-%d7%a4%d7%95%d7%93-%d7%a2%d7%9d-%d7%a0%d7%99%d7%a8-%d7%9c%d7%95%d7%99/"><img width="800" height="1200" src="http://outofsite.co.il/liat/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/8d18f3cf-6b0f-417c-9286-77aaf3f82c1a.jpg" class="attachment-full size-full wp-post-image" alt=""></a>
      <div class="workshop-date">
        ספטמבר, 2018
      </div>

    </div>
    <div class="workshop-title">
      <h3><a href="http://outofsite.co.il/liat/workshop/%d7%91%d7%99%d7%a9%d7%95%d7%9c-%d7%a8%d7%95%d7%90-%d7%a4%d7%95%d7%93-%d7%a2%d7%9d-%d7%a0%d7%99%d7%a8-%d7%9c%d7%95%d7%99/">בישול רוא פוד עם ניר לוי</a></h3>
      <p>מספר מפגשים: 2
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="workshop-promo">
      <a href="http://outofsite.co.il/liat/workshop/%d7%91%d7%99%d7%a9%d7%95%d7%9c-%d7%a8%d7%95%d7%90-%d7%a4%d7%95%d7%93-%d7%a2%d7%9d-%d7%a0%d7%99%d7%a8-%d7%9c%d7%95%d7%99/">
        <p>מטבח הרו-פוד הוא חגיגה קולינארית בכל קנה מידה. המטבח מאופיין בשפע טעמים חיים, צבעים, יופי ויצירתיות והכי חשוב שכל המתכונים שנילמד בקורס הזה, הם מתכונים קלים ומהירים להכנה. מתאימים לאורח חיים מודרני והמהיר שלנו.</p>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="workshop">
    <div class="workshop-img">
      <a href="http://outofsite.co.il/liat/workshop/%d7%a1%d7%93%d7%a0%d7%90%d7%aa-%d7%91%d7%99%d7%a9%d7%95%d7%9c-%d7%91%d7%95%d7%9b%d7%a8%d7%99%d7%aa-%d7%a2%d7%9d-%d7%9e%d7%99%d7%a7%d7%94-%d7%a9%d7%9e%d7%a2%d7%95%d7%a0%d7%95%d7%91/"><img width="1200" height="799" src="http://outofsite.co.il/liat/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/Mika.jpg" class="attachment-full size-full wp-post-image" alt=""></a>
      <div class="workshop-date">
        מאי, 2018
      </div>

    </div>
    <div class="workshop-title">
      <h3><a href="http://outofsite.co.il/liat/workshop/%d7%a1%d7%93%d7%a0%d7%90%d7%aa-%d7%91%d7%99%d7%a9%d7%95%d7%9c-%d7%91%d7%95%d7%9b%d7%a8%d7%99%d7%aa-%d7%a2%d7%9d-%d7%9e%d7%99%d7%a7%d7%94-%d7%a9%d7%9e%d7%a2%d7%95%d7%a0%d7%95%d7%91/">סדנאת בישול בוכרית עם מיקה שמעונוב</a></h3>
      <p>מספר מפגשים:
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="workshop-promo">
      <a href="http://outofsite.co.il/liat/workshop/%d7%a1%d7%93%d7%a0%d7%90%d7%aa-%d7%91%d7%99%d7%a9%d7%95%d7%9c-%d7%91%d7%95%d7%9b%d7%a8%d7%99%d7%aa-%d7%a2%d7%9d-%d7%9e%d7%99%d7%a7%d7%94-%d7%a9%d7%9e%d7%a2%d7%95%d7%a0%d7%95%d7%91/">
        <p>מסע קולינרי על דרך המשי הוא חוויה של ריחות, טעמים וצבעים. דרך המשי משתרעת מסין שבמזרח ועד טורקיה. המטבחים על דרך המשי הושפעו האחד מהשני ויצרו עירוב מרתק של טעמים ותרבויות ששזורות זו בזו. כבת לעולים מאוזבקיסטן, בשבילי, המטבח הבוכרי הוא בית.</p>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="workshop">
    <div class="workshop-img">
      <a href="http://outofsite.co.il/liat/workshop/%d7%a1%d7%93%d7%a0%d7%90%d7%aa-%d7%90%d7%a4%d7%99%d7%94-%d7%a7%d7%99%d7%a0%d7%95%d7%97%d7%99%d7%9d-%d7%9c%d7%a4%d7%a1%d7%97-%d7%a2%d7%9d-%d7%90%d7%9c%d7%95%d7%9f-%d7%a9%d7%91%d7%95/"><img width="1125" height="1126" src="http://outofsite.co.il/liat/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/IMG_9240.jpg" class="attachment-full size-full wp-post-image" alt=""></a>
      <div class="workshop-date">
        מרץ, 2018
      </div>

    </div>
    <div class="workshop-title">
      <h3><a href="http://outofsite.co.il/liat/workshop/%d7%a1%d7%93%d7%a0%d7%90%d7%aa-%d7%90%d7%a4%d7%99%d7%94-%d7%a7%d7%99%d7%a0%d7%95%d7%97%d7%99%d7%9d-%d7%9c%d7%a4%d7%a1%d7%97-%d7%a2%d7%9d-%d7%90%d7%9c%d7%95%d7%9f-%d7%a9%d7%91%d7%95/">סדנאת אפיה קינוחים לפסח עם אלון שבו</a></h3>
      <p>מספר מפגשים: 1
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="workshop-promo">
      <a href="http://outofsite.co.il/liat/workshop/%d7%a1%d7%93%d7%a0%d7%90%d7%aa-%d7%90%d7%a4%d7%99%d7%94-%d7%a7%d7%99%d7%a0%d7%95%d7%97%d7%99%d7%9d-%d7%9c%d7%a4%d7%a1%d7%97-%d7%a2%d7%9d-%d7%90%d7%9c%d7%95%d7%9f-%d7%a9%d7%91%d7%95/">
        <p>מטבח הרו-פוד הוא חגיגה קולינארית בכל קנה מידה. המטבח מאופיין בשפע טעמים חיים, צבעים, יופי ויצירתיות והכי חשוב שכל המתכונים שנילמד בקורס הזה, הם מתכונים קלים ומהירים להכנה. מתאימים לאורח חיים מודרני והמהיר שלנו.</p>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="workshop">
    <div class="workshop-img">
      <a href="http://outofsite.co.il/liat/workshop/%d7%a2%d7%a8%d7%91-%d7%a8%d7%a4%d7%a8%d7%9d-%d7%95%d7%98%d7%95%d7%a0%d7%99%d7%a1/"><img width="800" height="715" src="http://outofsite.co.il/liat/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/43062098_2011117495575336_2225091791483305984_n-1.jpg" class="attachment-full size-full wp-post-image" alt=""></a>
      <div class="workshop-date">
        דצמבר, 2017
      </div>

    </div>
    <div class="workshop-title">
      <h3><a href="http://outofsite.co.il/liat/workshop/%d7%a2%d7%a8%d7%91-%d7%a8%d7%a4%d7%a8%d7%9d-%d7%95%d7%98%d7%95%d7%a0%d7%99%d7%a1/">ערב רפרם וטוניס</a></h3>
      <p>מספר מפגשים: 3
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="workshop-promo">
      <a href="http://outofsite.co.il/liat/workshop/%d7%a2%d7%a8%d7%91-%d7%a8%d7%a4%d7%a8%d7%9d-%d7%95%d7%98%d7%95%d7%a0%d7%99%d7%a1/">
        <p>רפרם חדד הוא אמן ויזואלי וחוקר אוכל. הוא חוקר את הקשר בין קראפט לאמנות ותרבות עכשווית ובאוכל הוא עוסק בקשר בין אוכל יהודי, ים תיכוני וזה הביוגרפי שלו. הוא חי ועובד בתוניסיה, תורם מתכונים לספרים ובעבר עמד בראש תנועת סלואו פוד בישראל ולימד על אוכל
          באקדמיה לאמנות בבצלאל.</p>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="workshop">
    <div class="workshop-img">
      <a href="http://outofsite.co.il/liat/workshop/%d7%a1%d7%93%d7%a0%d7%90%d7%aa-%d7%a7%d7%99%d7%a0%d7%95%d7%97%d7%99-%d7%91%d7%95%d7%98%d7%99%d7%a7-%d7%a2%d7%9d-%d7%90%d7%a4%d7%a8%d7%aa-%d7%9c%d7%99%d7%91%d7%a4%d7%a8%d7%99%d7%95%d7%a0%d7%93/"><img width="1280" height="1106" src="http://outofsite.co.il/liat/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/1fb86d11-d893-46d2-b1f1-3d5e7f2dba25-1.jpg" class="attachment-full size-full wp-post-image" alt=""></a>
      <div class="workshop-date">
        נובמבר, 2017
      </div>

    </div>
    <div class="workshop-title">
      <h3><a href="http://outofsite.co.il/liat/workshop/%d7%a1%d7%93%d7%a0%d7%90%d7%aa-%d7%a7%d7%99%d7%a0%d7%95%d7%97%d7%99-%d7%91%d7%95%d7%98%d7%99%d7%a7-%d7%a2%d7%9d-%d7%90%d7%a4%d7%a8%d7%aa-%d7%9c%d7%99%d7%91%d7%a4%d7%a8%d7%99%d7%95%d7%a0%d7%93/">סדנאת קינוחי בוטיק עם אפרת ליבפריונד</a></h3>
      <p>מספר מפגשים: 3
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="workshop-promo">
      <a href="http://outofsite.co.il/liat/workshop/%d7%a1%d7%93%d7%a0%d7%90%d7%aa-%d7%a7%d7%99%d7%a0%d7%95%d7%97%d7%99-%d7%91%d7%95%d7%98%d7%99%d7%a7-%d7%a2%d7%9d-%d7%90%d7%a4%d7%a8%d7%aa-%d7%9c%d7%99%d7%91%d7%a4%d7%a8%d7%99%d7%95%d7%a0%d7%93/">
        <p>מטבח הרו-פוד הוא חגיגה קולינארית בכל קנה מידה. המטבח מאופיין בשפע טעמים חיים, צבעים, יופי ויצירתיות והכי חשוב שכל המתכונים שנילמד בקורס הזה, הם מתכונים קלים ומהירים להכנה. מתאימים לאורח חיים מודרני והמהיר שלנו.</p>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="workshop">
    <div class="workshop-img">
      <a href="http://outofsite.co.il/liat/workshop/%d7%a1%d7%93%d7%a0%d7%aa-%d7%90%d7%a4%d7%99%d7%94-%d7%a7%d7%99%d7%a0%d7%95%d7%97%d7%99%d7%99-%d7%91%d7%95%d7%98%d7%99%d7%a7/"><img width="800" height="1200" src="http://outofsite.co.il/liat/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/8d18f3cf-6b0f-417c-9286-77aaf3f82c1a.jpg" class="attachment-full size-full wp-post-image" alt=""></a>
      <div class="workshop-date">
        נובמבר, 2017
      </div>

    </div>
    <div class="workshop-title">
      <h3><a href="http://outofsite.co.il/liat/workshop/%d7%a1%d7%93%d7%a0%d7%aa-%d7%90%d7%a4%d7%99%d7%94-%d7%a7%d7%99%d7%a0%d7%95%d7%97%d7%99%d7%99-%d7%91%d7%95%d7%98%d7%99%d7%a7/">סדנת אפיה קינוחיי בוטיק</a></h3>
      <p>מספר מפגשים: 1
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="workshop-promo">
      <a href="http://outofsite.co.il/liat/workshop/%d7%a1%d7%93%d7%a0%d7%aa-%d7%90%d7%a4%d7%99%d7%94-%d7%a7%d7%99%d7%a0%d7%95%d7%97%d7%99%d7%99-%d7%91%d7%95%d7%98%d7%99%d7%a7/">
        <p>מטבח הרו-פוד הוא חגיגה קולינארית בכל קנה מידה. המטבח מאופיין בשפע טעמים חיים, צבעים, יופי ויצירתיות והכי חשוב שכל המתכונים שנילמד בקורס הזה, הם מתכונים קלים ומהירים להכנה. מתאימים לאורח חיים מודרני והמהיר שלנו.</p>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- WPV_Infinite_Scroll -->



</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/idoangel/7ybz6nrs/29/

Comment: Can you check again? I don't see anything wrong with the last column

Comment: each column has an image and text below. the last column (right most bottom) text is pushed to the next column and doesn't appear under the image...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/44377343/3597276

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `break-inside: avoid-column;` to `.workshop`.

```css
.workshop {
  width: 100% !important;
  margin: 0 0 1rem 0 !important;
  padding: 0 15px;
  float: right;
  break-inside: avoid-column;
}

.workshop-img {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  float: right;
  width: 100%;
}

.workshop-date {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  right: 0;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  background: white;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 20px 0 0 20px;
  color: black;
}

.js-wpv-view-layout {
  column-count: 2;
  -webkit-column-count: 2;
  column-gap: 15px;
  -webkit-column-gap: 15px;
  float: right;
  width: 100%;
  direction: rtl;
}

.workshop-title {
  margin-top: 1rem;
}

.workshop-promo {
  position: relative;
  float: right;
  margin-top: 1rem;
}

.workshop-promo p,
.workshop-promo a {
  color: black;
  text-align: justify;
}
```

```html
<div id="wpv-view-layout-10173" class="js-wpv-view-layout">



  <!-- WPV_Infinite_Scroll -->
  <!-- WPV_Infinite_Scroll_Insert -->
  <div class="workshop">
    <div class="workshop-img">
      <a href="http://outofsite.co.il/liat/workshop/%d7%a1%d7%93%d7%a0%d7%90-%d7%9b%d7%aa%d7%95%d7%9e%d7%94-%d7%a2%d7%9d-%d7%93%d7%9c%d7%99%d7%aa-%d7%a7%d7%a4%d7%9c%d7%9f/"><img width="800" height="798" src="http://outofsite.co.il/liat/wp-content/uploads/2018/12/Dalit-kaplan-1.jpg" class="attachment-full size-full wp-post-image" alt=""></a>
      <div class="workshop-date">
        נובמבר, 2018
      </div>

    </div>
    <div class="workshop-title">
      <h3><a href="http://outofsite.co.il/liat/workshop/%d7%a1%d7%93%d7%a0%d7%90-%d7%9b%d7%aa%d7%95%d7%9e%d7%94-%d7%a2%d7%9d-%d7%93%d7%9c%d7%99%d7%aa-%d7%a7%d7%a4%d7%9c%d7%9f/">סדנא כתומה עם דלית קפלן</a></h3>
      <p>מספר מפגשים: 1
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="workshop-promo">
      <a href="http://outofsite.co.il/liat/workshop/%d7%a1%d7%93%d7%a0%d7%90-%d7%9b%d7%aa%d7%95%d7%9e%d7%94-%d7%a2%d7%9d-%d7%93%d7%9c%d7%99%d7%aa-%d7%a7%d7%a4%d7%9c%d7%9f/">
        <p>תודו שאם לשים משקפיים ורודות אז שיהיו מקרונים. אז דלית ואני רקחנו לכם סדנא כתומה לכבוד טנקסגיבינג, עם פחזניות וסטיקי באנס ומלא הפתעות כתומות אחרות. ורק בשביל הפאן נגיע בפיג'מות, נדליק את האח ואם תהיו ילדים טובים נעשה לכם גם סיידר.&nbsp;אם כבר
          אז כבר.</p>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="workshop">
    <div class="workshop-img">
      <a href="http://outofsite.co.il/liat/workshop/%d7%91%d7%99%d7%a9%d7%95%d7%9c-%d7%a8%d7%95%d7%90-%d7%a4%d7%95%d7%93-%d7%a2%d7%9d-%d7%a0%d7%99%d7%a8-%d7%9c%d7%95%d7%99/"><img width="800" height="1200" src="http://outofsite.co.il/liat/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/8d18f3cf-6b0f-417c-9286-77aaf3f82c1a.jpg" class="attachment-full size-full wp-post-image" alt=""></a>
      <div class="workshop-date">
        ספטמבר, 2018
      </div>

    </div>
    <div class="workshop-title">
      <h3><a href="http://outofsite.co.il/liat/workshop/%d7%91%d7%99%d7%a9%d7%95%d7%9c-%d7%a8%d7%95%d7%90-%d7%a4%d7%95%d7%93-%d7%a2%d7%9d-%d7%a0%d7%99%d7%a8-%d7%9c%d7%95%d7%99/">בישול רוא פוד עם ניר לוי</a></h3>
      <p>מספר מפגשים: 2
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="workshop-promo">
      <a href="http://outofsite.co.il/liat/workshop/%d7%91%d7%99%d7%a9%d7%95%d7%9c-%d7%a8%d7%95%d7%90-%d7%a4%d7%95%d7%93-%d7%a2%d7%9d-%d7%a0%d7%99%d7%a8-%d7%9c%d7%95%d7%99/">
        <p>מטבח הרו-פוד הוא חגיגה קולינארית בכל קנה מידה. המטבח מאופיין בשפע טעמים חיים, צבעים, יופי ויצירתיות והכי חשוב שכל המתכונים שנילמד בקורס הזה, הם מתכונים קלים ומהירים להכנה. מתאימים לאורח חיים מודרני והמהיר שלנו.</p>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="workshop">
    <div class="workshop-img">
      <a href="http://outofsite.co.il/liat/workshop/%d7%a1%d7%93%d7%a0%d7%90%d7%aa-%d7%91%d7%99%d7%a9%d7%95%d7%9c-%d7%91%d7%95%d7%9b%d7%a8%d7%99%d7%aa-%d7%a2%d7%9d-%d7%9e%d7%99%d7%a7%d7%94-%d7%a9%d7%9e%d7%a2%d7%95%d7%a0%d7%95%d7%91/"><img width="1200" height="799" src="http://outofsite.co.il/liat/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/Mika.jpg" class="attachment-full size-full wp-post-image" alt=""></a>
      <div class="workshop-date">
        מאי, 2018
      </div>

    </div>
    <div class="workshop-title">
      <h3><a href="http://outofsite.co.il/liat/workshop/%d7%a1%d7%93%d7%a0%d7%90%d7%aa-%d7%91%d7%99%d7%a9%d7%95%d7%9c-%d7%91%d7%95%d7%9b%d7%a8%d7%99%d7%aa-%d7%a2%d7%9d-%d7%9e%d7%99%d7%a7%d7%94-%d7%a9%d7%9e%d7%a2%d7%95%d7%a0%d7%95%d7%91/">סדנאת בישול בוכרית עם מיקה שמעונוב</a></h3>
      <p>מספר מפגשים:
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="workshop-promo">
      <a href="http://outofsite.co.il/liat/workshop/%d7%a1%d7%93%d7%a0%d7%90%d7%aa-%d7%91%d7%99%d7%a9%d7%95%d7%9c-%d7%91%d7%95%d7%9b%d7%a8%d7%99%d7%aa-%d7%a2%d7%9d-%d7%9e%d7%99%d7%a7%d7%94-%d7%a9%d7%9e%d7%a2%d7%95%d7%a0%d7%95%d7%91/">
        <p>מסע קולינרי על דרך המשי הוא חוויה של ריחות, טעמים וצבעים. דרך המשי משתרעת מסין שבמזרח ועד טורקיה. המטבחים על דרך המשי הושפעו האחד מהשני ויצרו עירוב מרתק של טעמים ותרבויות ששזורות זו בזו. כבת לעולים מאוזבקיסטן, בשבילי, המטבח הבוכרי הוא בית.</p>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="workshop">
    <div class="workshop-img">
      <a href="http://outofsite.co.il/liat/workshop/%d7%a1%d7%93%d7%a0%d7%90%d7%aa-%d7%90%d7%a4%d7%99%d7%94-%d7%a7%d7%99%d7%a0%d7%95%d7%97%d7%99%d7%9d-%d7%9c%d7%a4%d7%a1%d7%97-%d7%a2%d7%9d-%d7%90%d7%9c%d7%95%d7%9f-%d7%a9%d7%91%d7%95/"><img width="1125" height="1126" src="http://outofsite.co.il/liat/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/IMG_9240.jpg" class="attachment-full size-full wp-post-image" alt=""></a>
      <div class="workshop-date">
        מרץ, 2018
      </div>

    </div>
    <div class="workshop-title">
      <h3><a href="http://outofsite.co.il/liat/workshop/%d7%a1%d7%93%d7%a0%d7%90%d7%aa-%d7%90%d7%a4%d7%99%d7%94-%d7%a7%d7%99%d7%a0%d7%95%d7%97%d7%99%d7%9d-%d7%9c%d7%a4%d7%a1%d7%97-%d7%a2%d7%9d-%d7%90%d7%9c%d7%95%d7%9f-%d7%a9%d7%91%d7%95/">סדנאת אפיה קינוחים לפסח עם אלון שבו</a></h3>
      <p>מספר מפגשים: 1
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="workshop-promo">
      <a href="http://outofsite.co.il/liat/workshop/%d7%a1%d7%93%d7%a0%d7%90%d7%aa-%d7%90%d7%a4%d7%99%d7%94-%d7%a7%d7%99%d7%a0%d7%95%d7%97%d7%99%d7%9d-%d7%9c%d7%a4%d7%a1%d7%97-%d7%a2%d7%9d-%d7%90%d7%9c%d7%95%d7%9f-%d7%a9%d7%91%d7%95/">
        <p>מטבח הרו-פוד הוא חגיגה קולינארית בכל קנה מידה. המטבח מאופיין בשפע טעמים חיים, צבעים, יופי ויצירתיות והכי חשוב שכל המתכונים שנילמד בקורס הזה, הם מתכונים קלים ומהירים להכנה. מתאימים לאורח חיים מודרני והמהיר שלנו.</p>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="workshop">
    <div class="workshop-img">
      <a href="http://outofsite.co.il/liat/workshop/%d7%a2%d7%a8%d7%91-%d7%a8%d7%a4%d7%a8%d7%9d-%d7%95%d7%98%d7%95%d7%a0%d7%99%d7%a1/"><img width="800" height="715" src="http://outofsite.co.il/liat/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/43062098_2011117495575336_2225091791483305984_n-1.jpg" class="attachment-full size-full wp-post-image" alt=""></a>
      <div class="workshop-date">
        דצמבר, 2017
      </div>

    </div>
    <div class="workshop-title">
      <h3><a href="http://outofsite.co.il/liat/workshop/%d7%a2%d7%a8%d7%91-%d7%a8%d7%a4%d7%a8%d7%9d-%d7%95%d7%98%d7%95%d7%a0%d7%99%d7%a1/">ערב רפרם וטוניס</a></h3>
      <p>מספר מפגשים: 3
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="workshop-promo">
      <a href="http://outofsite.co.il/liat/workshop/%d7%a2%d7%a8%d7%91-%d7%a8%d7%a4%d7%a8%d7%9d-%d7%95%d7%98%d7%95%d7%a0%d7%99%d7%a1/">
        <p>רפרם חדד הוא אמן ויזואלי וחוקר אוכל. הוא חוקר את הקשר בין קראפט לאמנות ותרבות עכשווית ובאוכל הוא עוסק בקשר בין אוכל יהודי, ים תיכוני וזה הביוגרפי שלו. הוא חי ועובד בתוניסיה, תורם מתכונים לספרים ובעבר עמד בראש תנועת סלואו פוד בישראל ולימד על אוכל
          באקדמיה לאמנות בבצלאל.</p>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="workshop">
    <div class="workshop-img">
      <a href="http://outofsite.co.il/liat/workshop/%d7%a1%d7%93%d7%a0%d7%90%d7%aa-%d7%a7%d7%99%d7%a0%d7%95%d7%97%d7%99-%d7%91%d7%95%d7%98%d7%99%d7%a7-%d7%a2%d7%9d-%d7%90%d7%a4%d7%a8%d7%aa-%d7%9c%d7%99%d7%91%d7%a4%d7%a8%d7%99%d7%95%d7%a0%d7%93/"><img width="1280" height="1106" src="http://outofsite.co.il/liat/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/1fb86d11-d893-46d2-b1f1-3d5e7f2dba25-1.jpg" class="attachment-full size-full wp-post-image" alt=""></a>
      <div class="workshop-date">
        נובמבר, 2017
      </div>

    </div>
    <div class="workshop-title">
      <h3><a href="http://outofsite.co.il/liat/workshop/%d7%a1%d7%93%d7%a0%d7%90%d7%aa-%d7%a7%d7%99%d7%a0%d7%95%d7%97%d7%99-%d7%91%d7%95%d7%98%d7%99%d7%a7-%d7%a2%d7%9d-%d7%90%d7%a4%d7%a8%d7%aa-%d7%9c%d7%99%d7%91%d7%a4%d7%a8%d7%99%d7%95%d7%a0%d7%93/">סדנאת קינוחי בוטיק עם אפרת ליבפריונד</a></h3>
      <p>מספר מפגשים: 3
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="workshop-promo">
      <a href="http://outofsite.co.il/liat/workshop/%d7%a1%d7%93%d7%a0%d7%90%d7%aa-%d7%a7%d7%99%d7%a0%d7%95%d7%97%d7%99-%d7%91%d7%95%d7%98%d7%99%d7%a7-%d7%a2%d7%9d-%d7%90%d7%a4%d7%a8%d7%aa-%d7%9c%d7%99%d7%91%d7%a4%d7%a8%d7%99%d7%95%d7%a0%d7%93/">
        <p>מטבח הרו-פוד הוא חגיגה קולינארית בכל קנה מידה. המטבח מאופיין בשפע טעמים חיים, צבעים, יופי ויצירתיות והכי חשוב שכל המתכונים שנילמד בקורס הזה, הם מתכונים קלים ומהירים להכנה. מתאימים לאורח חיים מודרני והמהיר שלנו.</p>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="workshop">
    <div class="workshop-img">
      <a href="http://outofsite.co.il/liat/workshop/%d7%a1%d7%93%d7%a0%d7%aa-%d7%90%d7%a4%d7%99%d7%94-%d7%a7%d7%99%d7%a0%d7%95%d7%97%d7%99%d7%99-%d7%91%d7%95%d7%98%d7%99%d7%a7/"><img width="800" height="1200" src="http://outofsite.co.il/liat/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/8d18f3cf-6b0f-417c-9286-77aaf3f82c1a.jpg" class="attachment-full size-full wp-post-image" alt=""></a>
      <div class="workshop-date">
        נובמבר, 2017
      </div>

    </div>
    <div class="workshop-title">
      <h3><a href="http://outofsite.co.il/liat/workshop/%d7%a1%d7%93%d7%a0%d7%aa-%d7%90%d7%a4%d7%99%d7%94-%d7%a7%d7%99%d7%a0%d7%95%d7%97%d7%99%d7%99-%d7%91%d7%95%d7%98%d7%99%d7%a7/">סדנת אפיה קינוחיי בוטיק</a></h3>
      <p>מספר מפגשים: 1
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="workshop-promo">
      <a href="http://outofsite.co.il/liat/workshop/%d7%a1%d7%93%d7%a0%d7%aa-%d7%90%d7%a4%d7%99%d7%94-%d7%a7%d7%99%d7%a0%d7%95%d7%97%d7%99%d7%99-%d7%91%d7%95%d7%98%d7%99%d7%a7/">
        <p>מטבח הרו-פוד הוא חגיגה קולינארית בכל קנה מידה. המטבח מאופיין בשפע טעמים חיים, צבעים, יופי ויצירתיות והכי חשוב שכל המתכונים שנילמד בקורס הזה, הם מתכונים קלים ומהירים להכנה. מתאימים לאורח חיים מודרני והמהיר שלנו.</p>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- WPV_Infinite_Scroll -->



</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

ok, so it was kinda simple. just had to add

```
.workshow {break-inside: avoid-column;}
```

and it worked like a charm!

updated fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/idoangel/7ybz6nrs/33/

Comment: This is exactly what ksav's answer from December says to do. You should mark it as the correct answer by clicking the checkmark (you will even gain some reputation by doing that!) to show readers that it solves the problem, and then delete this answer.

Comment: Oops, didn't even see it! Apologies

Comment: No worries; SO is quite a complex site with a lot of easy-to-miss features/functionality!

Answer (score 0):

I had to set the `break-inside` on the items inside the container

see https://stackoverflow.com/a/76474266/5985680